# Python plotting a function and limits

Tags: python-2.7

Hi I am new to python and I am using version 2.7. I came across a problem which requires me to plot a function:

f(z) = (z^3) / {exp[z/(1-z)] * (1-z)^5}

I have to write a code to plot f(z) from z = 0.01 to 0.99. And I have to guess the value of the following:

1. lim z->0+ of f(z)
2. lim z->0-  of f(z)

I am really new to python and I have no idea where to start. Really appreciate it if you can offer some help thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

For plotting software, you really should go for the package Matplotlib, which is part of the greater package SciPy (which is basically a must for any type of plotting or computational work in python).

http://matplotlib.org/

Ask for how to plot the function, we could first generate a linespace with 50 points from 0-1.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> z = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
>>> print z
array([ 0.        ,  0.02040816,  0.04081633,  0.06122449,  0.08163265,
    0.10204082,  0.12244898,  0.14285714,  0.16326531,  0.18367347,
    0.20408163,  0.2244898 ,  0.24489796,  0.26530612,  0.28571429,
    0.30612245,  0.32653061,  0.34693878,  0.36734694,  0.3877551 ,
    0.40816327,  0.42857143,  0.44897959,  0.46938776,  0.48979592,
    0.51020408,  0.53061224,  0.55102041,  0.57142857,  0.59183673,
    0.6122449 ,  0.63265306,  0.65306122,  0.67346939,  0.69387755,
    0.71428571,  0.73469388,  0.75510204,  0.7755102 ,  0.79591837,
    0.81632653,  0.83673469,  0.85714286,  0.87755102,  0.89795918,
    0.91836735,  0.93877551,  0.95918367,  0.97959184,  1.        ])
```

Then, we need to return a function offered.

> > > def somefunc(z):
> > >           return (z**3)/(np.exp(z/(1-z)) * (1-z)**5)

And then calculate the function's values for z:

```
>>> y = somefunc(z)
>>> print y
array([  0.00000000e+00,   9.22864991e-06,   8.02624183e-05,
     2.94878571e-04,   7.61913399e-04,   1.62437817e-03,
     3.06834651e-03,   5.33405408e-03,   8.72976295e-03,
     1.36490830e-02,   2.05926181e-02,   3.01950261e-02,
     4.32588543e-02,   6.07968601e-02,   8.40849466e-02,
     1.14728376e-01,   1.54744559e-01,   2.06666502e-01,
     2.73671906e-01,   3.59743965e-01,   4.69871087e-01,
     6.10293896e-01,   7.88808903e-01,   1.01513861e+00,
     1.30137704e+00,   1.66251622e+00,   2.11705156e+00,
     2.68764730e+00,   3.40181327e+00,   4.29248886e+00,
     5.39833448e+00,   6.76336940e+00,   8.43532836e+00,
     1.04616864e+01,   1.28816588e+01,   1.57115818e+01,
     1.89200055e+01,   2.23880593e+01,   2.58517231e+01,
     2.88295260e+01,   3.05606009e+01,   3.00285648e+01,
     2.62351130e+01,   1.89494883e+01,   9.86526435e+00,
     2.77918094e+00,   2.10803261e-01,   4.84858966e-04,
     3.78425803e-13,              nan])
```

As you can see, it calculated the  value of the function at each point in the linespace. Now it should give you a zero divide error, producing nan, (since the divisor is 0 at 1), which you can ignore with the following:

```
>>> def somefunc(z):
>>>     with no.errstate(all='ignore'):
>>>         return (z**3)/(np.exp(z/(1-z)) * (1-z)**5)
```

Now we need to plot the image:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.figure()
<matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x7f44eeebc1d0>
>>> plt.plot(z, y, 'red')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f44ef17db90>]
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: Here is what is plotted. As you can see, the z is the horizontal labels and y is the vertical labels.]

As for the limits, the function seems to clearly define what those are. To validate, just look at the linespace. If you need more complex limit finding, check out the core SciPy stack.